# 「２０歳以上での年齢」- Why include this で?

Tags: nuances, particles, particle-で

In a store's liquor section in Japan, a sign reads: 「20歳以上での年齢であることを確認できない場合には酒類を販売致しません。」

What is the purpose of the particle で in 「20歳以上での年齢」, and is the meaning any different if 「20歳以上の年齢」 without で were used instead?

Edit: Here is the sign in question: https://postimg.cc/3yVyhTP4

Comment: It must be a mistake. There should be no で there.

Comment: Hmm, interesting. For the record I added my picture of the sign to the question. Thanks

Comment: They made it redundant by adding 年齢 later and introduced an error in the process...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like a typo. Perhaps they rewrote it from 「20歳以上であることを確認できない場合には...」 and left out one redundant で accidentally.